# htpasswd, Magento, and the Image Uploader HTTP error

Tags: flash, magento, .htpasswd

When I password protect a Magento site with htaccess/ htpasswd, it causes the flash uploader to error. I'm aware of this problem with the request from Flash being rejected. I normally throw on a plugin that prevents the need for Flash (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Tobias+Renger/extension/1756/no-flash-uploader).

I also know there's a solution to let the file being accessed be excused from the password protection, which I use for Wordpress quite a lot, for the same problem. I'm not sure which php file the flash uploader accesses though, so I don't know which file to put in:

```
<FilesMatch "(the-file\.php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
</FilesMatch>
```

Does someone know off hand which file the Flash Uploader targets? I would love to conquer this problem once and for all!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try using this in the .htaccess file.

```
<LimitExcept POST>
    require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for auth and Magento Flash uploader.

```
<LocationMatch "/catalog_product_gallery/upload">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```